# MAMP PHP date.timezone incorrect

Tags: php, macos, date, time, mamp

I am using MAMP to run some local PHP pages in my browser for school and I am having a weird issues where my timezone is stuck on "Europe/Berlin". I have manually set it to `date.timezone = "America\Los_Angeles"` in the 5.4.4 php.ini file (and double checked that is the version that MAMP is using) but no luck. I made sure my time zone in system preferences was set to West Coast time and tried it both with automatic time zone detection and without, but still nothing. Finally, I edited my .profile file, adding `export TZ="America/Los_Angeles"` but no change.

In the phpInfo tab in the MAMP start page is says both the local value and master value are set to `Europe/Berlin` and I have no idea how to change it. Any thoughts?

Edit: I restarted MAMP after every change

Comment: Restart the MAMP (specifically, Apache) service once you edit the php.ini file.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention I did that after every change

Comment: Based on the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), PHP retrieves its timezone setting from a specific precedence of sources.  Perhaps you should try using `date_default_timezone_set()` in your .ini file, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck. I also tried throwing that into my php page right before I call `date()` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am starting to wonder whether there might be a problem with the native OSX PHP installation and your MAMP installation.  Can you run your script with `date_default_timezone_set()` from the command line and see a change in the timezone?  I still would have expected the timezpne to change when you inserted `date_default_timezone_set()` directly into the script though.  Nevertheless I am still curious to know what happens from the command line.  Also, what is the output of `which php` in the terminal?  You may also look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795068).

Comment: A little bit late, but this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795068/mamp-php-ini-date-timezone-setting-in-phpinfo-shows-no-value-even-thoug