# Mamp DateTime() not reflecting settings. Incorrect time zone

Tags: php, apache, date, datetime, mamp

I have basically the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583142/mamp-php-date-timezone-incorrect), but there is no answer.

I am using php5.3.29 to reflect the version on my live site.
I have set `date.timezone = "America/Chicago"` in `MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/conf/php.ini`, but when I call `DateTime(date('Y-m-d G:i'))` it returns UTC time, instead of Chicago time.

Yes, I have restarted Mamp since changing that.  Also phpinfo() shows the timezone as America/Chicago.

What's the deal?

---

**Edit**

I now tried adding `date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");` in my function directly before calling DateTime() and I get the desired results, but this just isn't right.  That doesn't help my error logs...

---

**Digging Deeper**

`date_default_timezone_get()` returns UTC, while `ini_get('date.timezone')` returns America/Chicago

Comment: DateTime takes a timestamp as the constructor note a date

Comment: In my case above date('Y-m-d G:i') returns something like: '2015-07-22 20:25'.  Why would DateTime have any trouble with that?  It's just a way for me to get the current time.

Comment: Not to mention, since your comment, I made the edit above, which shows that is not a problem.

Comment: In my case, I set the value in php.ini without brakets like so: `date.timezone = America/Montreal`. Maybe you could try this.

Comment: Tried that, but upon restarting Mamp, it adds the quotes back.

Comment: Do you display or log E_NOTICE errors? If the timezone is invalid (for some weird reason, because it looks valid), it would throw E_NOTICE errors. Also, does phpinfo show "America/Chicago" as the master or local value?

Comment: I turned display_errors on. Error_reporting was already set to error_reporting  =  E_ALL.  I get no errors displayed on the screen.  phpinfo shows both master and local as "America/Chicago.